# How to call a snowflake procedure

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requiremnet where i need to have a procedure calling another procedure .how can we invoke a another procedure within a procedure

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please read the article "How to ask" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). :)

Comment: You may have a look at the following discussion which is on similar lines: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009VvipRSAR/how-do-i-call-a-procedure-into-another-procedure

Comment: Just like you execute any other statement inside procedure using the Stored Procedures API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a procedure from a procedure just execute it like any other SQL query inside a procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_CALL_SP(PARAM1 TEXT)
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
 
    var param2 = 12345;
    var return_rows = [];
 
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
        sqlText: 'CALL TEST_CALLED_SP(:1, :2)',
        binds: [PARAM1, param2]
    });
    
    var result = stmt.execute();
    result.next();
    return_rows.push(result.getColumnValue(1))
    
    return return_rows;
    
$$
```

The sql in `sqlText: 'CALL TEST_CALLED_SP(:1, :2)'` above is calling the `TEST_CALLED_SP` procedure from inside the procedure.

For the complete code, check the link that Srinath posted: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009VvipRSAR/how-do-i-call-a-procedure-into-another-procedure